# Does ++ operator in CPP have any overload for char?

Tags: c++

Does the operator ++ have an overload to deal with char? 
Or 
Is this the flow of things?

```
++ <char> will lead to the following events: 
a char -> gets converted to int -> ++ increments it -> Gets converted back to char
```

The below code:

```
char test = 'a';
std::cout << test << std::endl;
std::cout << ++test << std::endl;
```

outputs

```
a
b
```

- How does this work internally? Is there some kind of implicit type conversion taking place for the ++ operator or is there a overload in the cpp standard for char.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec
says that there are overloads for only arithmetic and iterator types.

Comment: Are you aware that `char` is an arithmetic type? See [type classification @ cppreference,com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Type_classification).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char` *is* numeric, it's just special in a number of APIs such that it is rendered as an ASCII character (locale dependent, but ASCII is the common base encoding). `'a'` is just a convenient way to spell `(char)97`. So all `++` does is increment `97` to `98`, and `std::cout` knows to format `char` as the ASCII character with that ordinal, `'b'`.

Point is, `char` doesn't need additional overloads because it *is* an arithmetic type.

Comment: Note: `char`'s other bit of weirdness is the implementation defined signedness. If you actually want to use it for numeric purposes, you *should* explicitly specify `signed char` or `unsigned char` to avoid portability issues. But in this specific case, it's not approaching any values where the signedness matters, so it works regardless of what the compiler chose.

Comment: offtop: is `bool` an arithmetic type? upd it is, so why since C++17 `operator++` cannot applied for `bool`?

Comment: @user3365922 I think it makes no sense to apply ++ operator on bool. If you increase a false value, may be one could argue it should be true. But what would ++ on a bool value of true mean? It cannot be more true or be false. May be that's why they deprecated it in CPP17